# couchbase unable to resolve symbol getViewId()

Tags: java, android, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I updated couchbase from 1.0.4 to 1.2.0 and got an error with com.couchbase.lite.view object saying "cannot resolve symbol "couchbaseView.getViewId()". What is the replacement for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer API supports getting Views by name.  Look at the Properties table in the documentation [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/references/couchbase-lite/couchbase-lite/view/view/index.html).

I'd recommend jumping to v1.3.1 at this point, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

android dont have this method,if you sure this method is define,you could try to clean project

Comment: its a couchbase method. It was available with old versions of couchbase, like 1.0.4 . But they seem to have removed it from version 1.2.0.